# Some problems [warnings] by working with GtkTreeView in GTK+

Tags: c++, gtk, glade

I have already a GTK+ application. There are a few widgets: GtkWindow, GtkTreeView,  GtkListStore. All user interface was created in Glade.

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *topWindow;
    GtkTreeView *treeView;
    GtkListStore  *treeStore;

    GError *error = NULL;
    gtk_init( &argc, &argv ); 
    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    if( ! gtk_builder_add_from_file( builder, UI_FILE, &error ) )
    {
        g_warning( "%s", error->message );
        g_free( error );
        return( 1 );
    }


   topWindow = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "topWindow"));
   treeStore = GTK_LIST_STORE(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "liststore"));
   treeView = GTK_TREE_VIEW(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "treeview"));

   entry1 = GTK_ENTRY(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "entry1"));
   entry2 = GTK_ENTRY(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "entry2"));
   entry3 = GTK_ENTRY(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "entry3"));

   gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, NULL); 
   g_object_unref( G_OBJECT( builder ) );

   gtk_widget_show( topWindow );

   gtk_main();

   return( 0 );
}
```

The compilation is successful:

```
igor@igor-desktop:~/proj/TreeView_example$ make
gcc -Wall -g `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 gmodule-2.0` -c charter.c
gcc `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0 gmodule-2.0` charter.o -o charter
```

When I run the application, I get some warnings:

```
(charter:3728): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: value "466" of type `gint' is invalid or out of range for property `xalign' of type `gfloat'

(charter:3728): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: value "44" of type `gint' is invalid or out of range for property `xalign' of type `gfloat'

(charter:3728): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: value "466" of type `gint' is invalid or out of range for property `xalign' of type `gfloat'

(charter:3728): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: value "466" of type `gint' is invalid or out of range for property `xalign' of type `gfloat'

(charter:3728): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: value "44" of type `gint' is invalid or out of range for property `xalign' of type `gfloat'

(charter:3728): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: value "44" of type `gint' is invalid or out of range for property `xalign' of type `gfloat'

(charter:3728): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: value "466" of type `gint' is invalid or out of range for property `xalign' of type `gfloat'

(charter:3728): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: value "466" of type `gint' is invalid or out of range for property `xalign' of type `gfloat'

(charter:3728): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: value "44" of type `gint' is invalid or out of range for property `xalign' of type `gfloat'

(charter:3728): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: value "44" of type `gint' is invalid or out of range for property `xalign' of type `gfloat'
```

This is a part of Glade XML file, which contains the description of GtkTreeView:

```
 <object class="GtkTreeView" id="treeview">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="model">liststore</property>
                <property name="search_column">2</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn1">
                    <property name="title">&#x418;&#x43C;&#x44F;</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="cellrenderertext1"/>
                      <attributes>
                        <attribute name="xalign">0</attribute>
                        <attribute name="sensitive">0</attribute>
                        <attribute name="text">0</attribute>
                      </attributes>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn2">
                    <property name="title">&#x418;&#x43A;&#x441;</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="cellrenderertext2"/>
                      <attributes>
                        <attribute name="text">1</attribute>
                      </attributes>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn3">
                    <property name="title">&#x418;&#x433;&#x440;&#x435;&#x43A;</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="cellrenderertext3"/>
                      <attributes>
                        <attribute name="text">2</attribute>
                      </attributes>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child type="label">
              <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes"><b>TreeView</b></property>
                <property name="use_markup">True</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
```

Can you explain why I get the warnings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<attribute name="xalign">0</attribute>
<attribute name="sensitive">0</attribute>
<attribute name="text">0</attribute>
```

This says that you want the *xalign*, *sensitive*, and *text* properties of the cell renderer to be set to the value of column 0.

For example, if a row in your model looks like this:

```
column0=A  column1=B  column2=C
```

those lines in the xml will set the *xalign*, *sensitive*, and *text* of the first cell to *A*, whatever value A is, which is most likely not what you want.

---

In Glade, you can change these settings by right-clicking on the treeview, selecting *Edit...*, and then going to the *Hierarchy* tab. You should see three columns with one cell renderer each.

The rest depends on what you want to do. If you don't know what *[xalign](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkCellRenderer.html#GtkCellRenderer--xalign)* and *[sensitive](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkCellRenderer.html#GtkCellRenderer--sensitive)* are, they were probably set by accident, so just change them back to -1 (this is equivalent to removing the corresponding *attribute* elements from the XML). *text* is probably correct, so leave it at 0.

If you want to learn more about cell renderer attributes, you can probably start from the [tree widget overview](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/TreeWidget.html) and [TreeViewColumn.add_attribute documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkTreeViewColumn.html#gtk-tree-view-column-add-attribute). Unfortunately these do not explain the concept very clearly; you may get better explanation elsewhere.

Comment: ok, and What is the value of xalign, sensitive, text I must set in XML?

Comment: And Where I can change this properties in Glade, i can't fine